# .NET - Access webservice (.asmx) method using WebRequest in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services

I got a .net project from client. Right now, I need to make a WebRequest to a WebService (.asmx). The problem is i dont know how call the method in that web service using web request from c#.

my code :

RunRoutines.aspx

```
string UseAddress = "http://localhost:31952/api/RunRoutines.asmx";
                string address = string.Format(UseAddress);
                HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
```

RunRoutines.asmx

```
public class RunRoutines : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

[WebMethod]
public string RunRR1()
{
    return "Hello World";
}
}
```

I need to access the RunRR1() method from the web request in RunRoutines.aspx. Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: have you added service reference in your aspx project?

Comment: Yep. I can access the page, but i dont know how to access the method.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can access it using the name of the reference you have given while adding service reference.

For example if it is `localHost` then you can try below code:

```
var yourService = new localHost.WebService();

yourService.RunRR1();
```

For more details have a look here:

[image]

Image ref: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/consuming-web-service-in-Asp-Net-web-application/

Which is [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/consuming-web-service-in-Asp-Net-web-application/) for more details .

Comment: Thanks for this, but i want to access the method 'RunRR1' in web service using web request. (HttpWebRequest)

Comment: try giving like this : string UseAddress = "http://localhost:31952/api/RunRoutines.asmx/RunRR1"; @MuhammadZaid